# Express-validator, POST error 500, express 4.14.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to validate some data for sign-up page, but when I try to use express-validator for this, but clearly I made a mistake somewhere in my code and I cannot find it on my own.

Someone can tell me where I'm making a mistake? Console messages for req.body and what I get from POST method when I'm try to submit data from html form:

```
{ username: 'abc', email: '', password: '', passwordConfirm: '' }
POST /signup 500 38.871 ms - 1529
```

And my code:

```js
var express          = require('express');

var bodyParser       = require('body-parser');
var mysql            = require('mysql');
var bcrypt           = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');

var app             = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(expressValidator());

var router          = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('signup');
});


router.post('/', function (req, res) { 
    

    var password    = req.body.password;
    var passConf    = req.body.passwordConfirm;
    var email       = req.body.email;
    var nameUser    = req.body.username;
    
    console.log(req.body);
    
    req.check('username','error').notEmpty();

    res.redirect('/login');
});


module.exports = router;
```

Comment: In normally 500 error is server error, you can get some information in console log of server.